# importing Data table to Excel text becomes numeric

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

Hi just want to ask I am trying to import Datatables to excel and one of the columns becomes exponent like 444201000100100 becomes 4442exp8? here's my script

```
protected void btnExportfromDt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strFilename = "FinanceforBulkupload.xls";
    UploadDataTableToExcel(LoadData(), strFilename);
}
protected void UploadDataTableToExcel(DataTable dtEmp,string filename)
{
    string attachment = "attachment; filename="+filename;
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    string tab = string.Empty;
    foreach (DataColumn dtcol in dtEmp.Columns)
    {
        Response.Write(tab + dtcol.ColumnName);
        tab = "\t";
    }
    Response.Write("\n");
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtEmp.Rows)
    {
        tab = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < dtEmp.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            Response.Write(tab + Convert.ToString(dr[j]));

            tab = "\t";
        }
        Response.Write("\n");
    }
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-append a single quote to the value before you store it.  Instead of:

```
444201000100100
```

store:

```
'444201000100100
```

Answer (score 0):

must write the cell formatted text but the method we're using to write the cell does not allow you to add formatting, you should try another method to write the Excel file

Comment: do you have any link recommendation? I don't want to use a grid.. My design is to go directly using  datatable to excel...

Answer (score 0):

You can also format the destination column to be of type text (or whatever Excel format you'd prefer), to prevent it from doing this as well as removing leading zeros and other interpretations of the "General" cell formating rules.

As you're creating your output document on-the-fly, you'd need to set either specific columns or the entire worksheet to have this format rule. in VBA, this command is:

```
Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "@" ' This is the Text format
```

In C#, you should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
Excel.Range rng = this.Application.get_Range("A:A");
rng.NumberFormat = "@";
```

However this would require a reference to the Excel object, and from your existing code it looks as though you're working without that for the moment.

Gary's Student's answer will work as well, but doing so will cause those cells to ignore any formatting that is applied later when it is opened in Excel. The user would be required to remove the leading ' manually to control the format as expected.

Comment: thanks for the help... is there any option without using an Excel object?

Answer (score 0):

You have different options as others proposed.

Understand that you are generating a CSV and not an Excel file so you are limited.

Since a cell format is an excel property and cannot be specified in a CSV file, I would recommend creating an excel file (.xlsx) with EPPlus and write code to specify the column format as TravelinGuy suggested. http://epplus.codeplex.com/

If you want to stick to CSV then you are limited as to how the data will be displayed in Excel. Either you accept that Excel infers a number format from what it is reading or you put a leading quote...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to manually perform minor encoding when sending data to Excel. This is true of the automation API as well as any text-based file formats like CSV or (as in your case) tab-separated files.

A robust solution must prepend a single `'` character to a string in the following cases.

- The string can be parsed as a number (Excel uses [`VariantChangeTypeEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221634.aspx), but since you're using C#, `Double.TryParse` will do the trick)
- The string already already starts with a tick (`'`). (For example, if you have the string `'quoted'`, Excel will interpret it as `quoted'` unless you put another single tick at the front -- `''quoted'`.)
- The string starts with an `=` character. Even in the case of CSV files, Excel inteprets this to be a worksheet function. Putting a tick at the front prevents this (e.g. `'=This is not a worksheet function`).

If you still find this unacceptable, please know that you have no other option when you're writing text files manually like you're doing. If you object so strongly, you can try using the [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) or some other 3rd-party tool for building Excel workbooks. However, given what looks like a very simple use case, you'll almost certainly end up with a more complex solution that is slower and requires more code. I recommend just sucking it up and writing a simple routine that abides by the rules above.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that you *can* just prepend a tick to *every* string you output. However, that's slightly not user friendly. When the user opens the workbook, they will see the data as you intended (with the initial ticks not showing). However, when the user edits a cell value, they *will* see the tick.